# How can stomp with RabbitMQ be faster than just a normal websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, stomp

Sending 100 000 messages of 300 characters from a python server to a JavaScript client using RabbitMQ and STOMP takes 10-20 seconds:

Python server:

```py
import stomp

PORT = 61613
LOCALHOST = '0.0.0.0'
conn = stomp.Connection11([(LOCALHOST, PORT)])  
# conn.start()
conn.connect('guest','guest')
# from time import sleep
from random import choice, randint
from string import ascii_uppercase
from time import time
conn.send(body="start",destination='/queue/test')
t = time()
for i in range(100000):
    conn.send(body=''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(300)),destination='/queue/test')
t = time() - t
conn.send(body="end",destination='/queue/test')
print()
print(100000, "took ", t*1000, " ms")

conn.disconnect()
```

JavaScript client:

```js
    <script>
        var client = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:15674/ws');
        var test = document.getElementById("test")
        client.debug = null;
        var date1 = null
        var date2 = null
        test.innerText = "READY... START!"

        var sub = function(d) {
            test.innerText = d.body
            if(d.body == "start") {
                date1 = new Date().valueOf()
            }
            
            if(d.body == "end") {
                date2 = new Date().valueOf()
                console.log(100000, "took ", date2 - date1, " ms")
            }
        }
        var on_connect = function(x) {
            id = client.subscribe("/queue/test", sub);
            console.log("connected")
        };
        var on_error =  function(e) {
          console.log('error', e);
        };
        
        client.connect('guest', 'guest', on_connect, on_error, '/');
    </script>
```

However, when I tried to do it with just a plain websocket, this takes at least 22 seconds:

Python server:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import random
import string
async def echo(websocket):
    print("connected")
    await websocket.send("start")

    for i in range(100000):
        await websocket.send(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(300)))

    await websocket.send("end")
    print("sent")

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()
```

javascript client:

```
<body>
    <div id="test">
        READY... SET... GO!!
    </div>
    <script>
        var time1 = null
        var time2 = null

        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8765/ws');
        socket.onmessage = function(e) {
            var server_message = e.data;
            if (server_message == "start") {
                time1 = new Date().valueOf()
            }
            if (server_message == "end") {
                time2 = new Date().valueOf()
                console.log("100000 messages took ", (time2 - time1) / 1000, "seconds")
            }
            document.getElementById("test").innerText = server_message
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Is there any reason for this? I thought STOMP is basically websocket + whatever RabbitMQ is doing (after all the client is receiving information through a websocket), so wouldn't it be slower than just a plain websocket? Or is the problem with asyncio?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think it might have something to do with the difference between the arguments to the `send` function in the two cases?  Why don't you make them exactly the same?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. I will try when I have time